# Powershell/Polymon Monitoring

Tags: powershell, batch-file

So my boss wants us to use Polymon monitoring to watch a server's print spooler, because it has recently been turning itself off for no reason. We have a simple bat script on the desktop of the server to run "net start spooler" when Polymon sees the spooler shut off. However, the script I am using does not run the bat file...here is what Polymon says:

> Monitor status is available through the following $Status object 
>   Properties: $Status.StatusID, $Status.Status   The following StatusID
>   values have corresponding Status values:  1=OK, 2=WARN, 3=FAIL
>
> Monitor Counters are available through the $Counters collection. 
>   This collection exposes a default Item property which retrieves a
>   Counter by index value, e.g. $Counters(0)  and also exposes a Counter
>   property that retrieves a Counter by name, e.g.
>   Counters.Counter("MyCounterName")
>
> Counter objects expose the following properties:  CounterName,
>   CounterValue

My script is:

```
cmd /c C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Desktop\start_spooler1.bat
```

Polymon says the script checks out, but when I manually shut the spooler service down, all I get is notifications and the spooler does not turn back on. Thoughts? I'm a total newb at Powershell...and Polymon requires the action script to either be in Powershell or VB, so I'm open to either that will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due simply to the spaces in the path to the batch script.  Put quotes around the path and it could work:

```
cmd /c "C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Desktop\start_spooler1.bat"
```

But note that you don't need to use cmd for this - powershell will run `.bat` and `.cmd` files itself.  Due to the spaces in the path, you will again need some quoting, and the `&` operator:

```
& "C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Desktop\start_spooler1.bat"
```

Comment: That still doesn't start the spooler for whatever reason. Polymon didn't like the &, but it took cmd /c and the quotes, but still didn't start the spooler service.